# How to get these values with XPath

Tags: php, xpath

**HTML**

```
<table id='dg' border='0'  class="Table">
  <tr>
    <td class='text'>id.</td>
    <td class='text'>file</td>
    <td class='text'>alt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='text'><input name='somename[]' type='hidden' value='1234'>
      1</td>
    <td class='text'><a href='#' onClick="javascript:openPopWindow('../../somefile.jpg');" ><img src='cms_thumb.php?imgsrc=somefile2.jpg' border='0' ></a></td>
    <td class='text'><input type='text' name='title[]' value='Value 1'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='text'><input name='somename[]2' type='hidden' value='2345'>
      2</td>
    <td class='text'><a href='#' onClick="javascript:openPopWindow('../../somefile2.jpg');" ><img src='thumb.php?imgsrc=somefile2.jpg' border='0' ></a></td>
    <td class='text'><input type='text' name='title[]' value='Value 2'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**OBJECTIVE**

Need to get img src filename and get value of the input field which have name=title[]

**WHAT I HAVE SO FAR**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $node) { 
    $img = $xpath->query('//img')->item(0); 
    $img = str_replace("\'","",$img->getAttribute('src'));
    $img = str_replace("cms_thumb.php?imgsrc=","",$img);
    echo $img.'<br>';
}
```

$img contains just first image and not other

Comment: +1 -- Well written question :)

Comment: `$xpath->query('//img')->item(0)` — well, you are _explicitly_ getting only the first image (item at index 0 in the list of the matched elements)

Comment: And your `$xpath` is based on the whole Dom, not only the first `td` node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<table id='dg' border='0'  class="Table">
  <tr>
    <td class='text'>id.</td>
    <td class='text'>file</td>
    <td class='text'>alt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='text'><input name='somename[]' type='hidden' value='1234'>
      1</td>
    <td class='text'><a href='#' onClick="javascript:openPopWindow('../../somefile.jpg');" ><img src='cms_thumb.php?imgsrc=somefile2.jpg' border='0' ></a></td>
    <td class='text'><input type='text' name='title[]' value='Value 1'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='text'><input name='somename[]2' type='hidden' value='2345'>
      2</td>
    <td class='text'><a href='#' onClick="javascript:openPopWindow('../../somefile2.jpg');" ><img src='thumb.php?imgsrc=somefile2.jpg' border='0' ></a></td>
    <td class='text'><input type='text' name='title[]' value='Value 2'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
HTML;


$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);


foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName("td") as $td){
    foreach($td->getElementsByTagName("img") as $img){
        $arr_img[] = array(
            "img" => $img->getAttribute("src"),
        );
    }
    foreach($td->getElementsByTagName("input") as $name){
        if ($name->getAttribute("name")==="title[]"){
            $arr_value[] = array(
                "value" => $name->getAttribute("value")
            );
        }
    }
}

var_dump($arr_img); // In this array will be img src's
var_dump($arr_value); // In this array will be values of input elements which name equal to title[]
```

`var_dump` Outputs will be =>

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["img"]=>
    string(34) "cms_thumb.php?imgsrc=somefile2.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["img"]=>
    string(30) "thumb.php?imgsrc=somefile2.jpg"
  }
}

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(7) "Value 1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(7) "Value 2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the context parameter of [`DOMXPath::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) together with a relative query and check if img and input elements exist at all (it's not the case in your first table row):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $node) { 
    $img = $xpath->query('.//img', $node)->item(0);
    $input = $xpath->query('.//input[@name="title[]"]', $node)->item(0);
    if ($img && $input) {
        echo $img->getAttribute('src'), ' - ';
        echo $input->getAttribute('value'), '<br>';
    }
}
```

This searches for the first `<img>` and `<input name="title[]">` elements anywhere in each table row. If the table structure is always exacltly like shown above, you can optimize the script with a more explicit XPath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$table = $dom->getElementById('dg');
$images = $xpath->query('tr/td/a/img', $table);
$inputs = $xpath->query('tr/td/input[@name="title[]"]', $table);
```

To get the attributes, iterate over `$images` and `$inputs` in parallel, for example with a [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/MultipleIterator):

```
$iterator = new MultipleIterator();
$iterator->attachIterator(new IteratorIterator($images));
$iterator->attachIterator(new IteratorIterator($inputs));
foreach ($iterator as $items) {
    $src = $items[0]->getAttribute('src');
    $value = $items[1]->getAttribute('value');
    echo $src, ' - ', $value, '<br>';
}
```